# How can whole tabular environments be left or right aligned in TikZ node text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, align, nodes

I have nodes in a matrix representing fundamental particles. Some nodes represent the particles and nodes below these nodes feature characteristics of the particles (e.g. charge). At the nodes that feature the characteristics are tabular environments to align the names and numbers of the characteristics. These tabular environments are being centered in the nodes when I want them to be left-aligned.

The difference in the positioning of the characteristics text can be seen in comparing the text of the gamma square with the text of the Z square. How can the code be changed such that the tabular environments are aligned similarly for all squares (i.e. with the left edge of "Mass" and so on being at a constant distance from the edge of the square)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{particleblue}=[
    rectangle,
    thick,
    draw=black,
    fill=blue!20,
    minimum size=80pt
]
\tikzstyle{particlegreen}=[
    rectangle,
    thick,
    draw=black,
    fill=green!20,
    minimum size=80pt
]
\tikzstyle{particlered}=[
    rectangle,
    thick,
    draw=black,
    fill=red!20,
    minimum size=80pt
]
\tikzstyle{particleyellow}=[
    rectangle,
    thick,
    draw=black,
    fill=yellow!40,
    minimum size=80pt
]

\tikzstyle{backgroundblue}=[
    rectangle,
    fill=blue!10,
    inner sep=0.2cm
]
\tikzstyle{backgroundgreen}=[
    rectangle,
    fill=green!10,
    inner sep=0.2cm
]
\tikzstyle{backgroundred}=[
    rectangle,
    fill=red!10,
    inner sep=0.2cm
]
\tikzstyle{backgroundyellow}=[
    rectangle,
    fill=yellow!40,
    inner sep=0.2cm
]

\newcommand\particleblue[5]{% {label}{name}{mass}{charge}{spin}
    \node (#1) [particleblue]{
        \Huge${\boldsymbol{#2}}$};
    \node[below=11pt]{%
        \tiny
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Mass:&${#3}$\\
        Charge:&${#4}$\\
        Spin:&${#5}$
        \end{tabular}
    };
}
\newcommand\particlegreen[5]{% {label}{name}{mass}{charge}{spin}
    \node (#1) [particlegreen]{
        \Huge${\boldsymbol{#2}}$};
    \node[below=11pt]{%
        \tiny
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Mass:&${#3}$\\
        Charge:&${#4}$\\
        Spin:&${#5}$
        \end{tabular}
    };
}
\newcommand\particlered[5]{% {label}{name}{mass}{charge}{spin}
    \node (#1) [particlered]{
        \Huge${\boldsymbol{#2}}$};
    \node[below=11pt]{%
        \tiny
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Mass:&${#3}$\\
        Charge:&${#4}$\\
        Spin:&${#5}$
        \end{tabular}
    };
}
\newcommand\particleyellow[5]{% {label}{name}{mass}{charge}{spin}
    \node (#1) [particleyellow]{
        \Huge${\boldsymbol{#2}}$};
    \node[below=11pt]{%
        \tiny
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Mass:&${#3}$\\
        Charge:&${#4}$\\
        Spin:&${#5}$
        \end{tabular}
    };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,text depth=0.00ex]
    % elements in a matrix
    \matrix[row sep=0.5cm,column sep=0.5cm, nodes={align=left}]{
        \particleblue{u}{u}{2.3\,\si{MeV/c^2}}{2/3}{1/2}&
        \particleblue{c}{c}{1.275\,\si{GeV/c^2}}{2/3}{1/2}&
        \particleblue{t}{t}{173.07\,\si{GeV/c^2}}{2/3}{1/2}&
        \particlered{g}{g}{0}{0}{1}&
        \particlegreen{H}{H}{126\,\si{GeV/c^2}}{0}{0}&
        \\
        \particleblue{d}{d}{4.8\,\si{MeV/c^2}}{-1/3}{1/2}&
        \particleblue{s}{s}{95\,\si{MeV/c^2}}{-1/3}{1/2}&
        \particleblue{b}{b}{4.18\,\si{GeV/c^2}}{-1/3}{1/2}&
        \particlered{gamma}{\gamma}{0}{0}{1}&
        \\
        \particleyellow{e}{e}{0.511\,\si{MeV/c^2}}{-1}{1/2}&
        \particleyellow{mu}{\mu}{105.7\,\si{MeV/c^2}}{-1}{1/2}&
        \particleyellow{tau}{\tau}{1.777\,\si{GeV/c^2}}{-1}{1/2}&
        \particlered{Z}{Z}{91.2\,\si{GeV/c^2}}{0}{1}&
        \\
        \particleyellow{nu_e}{\nu_{e}}{<2.2\,\si{eV/c^2}}{0}{1/2}&
        \particleyellow{nu_mu}{\nu_{\mu}}{0.17\,\si{MeV/c^2}}{0}{1/2}&
        \particleyellow{nu_tau}{\nu_{\tau}}{15.5\,\si{MeV/c^2}}{0}{1/2}&
        \particlered{W}{W}{80.4\,\si{GeV/c^2}}{\pm{1}}{1}&
        \\
    };
    % background rectanges
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node [
            backgroundblue,
            fit=(u) (b)
        ]{};
        \node [
            backgroundyellow,
            fit=(e) (nu_tau)
        ]{};
        \node [
            backgroundred,
            fit=(g) (W)
        ]{};
        \node [
            backgroundgreen,
            fit=(H)
        ]{};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you can specify the width of the `tabular` environment. This can be done by replacing `{ll}` with e.g. `{p{10pt}p{15pt}}` (the measures are just examples) or, probably better, by using `tabularx`.

Comment: @d3pd: The graviton is spin-2. See the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/rpp2018-list-graviton.pdf). Otherwise, very nice visual design.

Answer (score 3):

A completely different approach to design of your image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,positioning}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
    \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 6mm,
particle/.style args = {#1/#2/#3/#4/#5}{
        rectangle, draw, thick, fill=#2, 
        text width=80pt, minimum height=80pt,
        font=\Large\itshape\bfseries, align=center,
        node contents={#1\\ \mbox{}},
        path picture={
        \node [%
            inner sep=4pt, outer sep=0pt,
            text width=80pt, minimum height=20pt, align=center,
            font=\scriptsize,
            above=0pt of \ppbb.south]
            {\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}Xl@{}}
            Mass:   &   #3      \\
            Charge: &   $#4$    \\
            Spin:   &   $#5$
             \end{tabularx}
            };%end of node contents
                      }% end of path picture 
                         }% end particle style               
                ]
\node (p12) [particle=d/blue!20/\SI{2.3}{MeV/c^2}/{2/3}/{1/2}];
\node (p22) [particle=s/blue!20/\SI{95}{MeV/c^2}/{2/3}/{1/2},
             right=of p12];
\node (p32) [particle=b/blue!20/\SI{4.18}{MeV/c^2}/{-1/3}/{1/2},
             right=of p22] {};
\node (p42) [particle=$\boldsymbol{\gamma}$/red!20/ / / ,
             right=of p32];
%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [fill=blue!10, fit=(p12) (p32)]{};
    \node [fill= red!10, fit=(p42)]{};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Your problem is solved by use of `tabularx`. As you can notice, the design of nodes is completely different. This nodes can be easily integrated in your `\newcommand` definition and than they use in matrix as you done in your solution. Otherwise, nodes can be placed  as is proposed in above MWE or connected in chain.

In MWE I consider only second row of your image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the specification `@{}p{17pt}p{43pt}@{}` for the tabular environments for the particles, e.g.:

```
\newcommand\particleblue[5]{% {label}{name}{mass}{charge}{spin}
    \node (#1) [particleblue]{
        \Huge${\boldsymbol{#2}}$};
    \node[below=11pt]{%
        \tiny
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{17pt}p{43pt}@{}}
        Mass:&${#3}$\\
        Charge:&${#4}$\\
        Spin:&${#5}$
        \end{tabular}
    };
}
```

[image]